# Related Accounts does not show MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, meta

I use the same OpenID for all of my StackExchange accounts.  Recently I have noticed that my account on Meta doesn't appear in my related accounts list.

All my accounts display correctly if I view them on Meta but not on any other site.

Edit:
I should point out that my Meta account used to display everywhere.

Comment: By Jove, you're right!

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that some new code was introduced that causes related accounts to treat Meta Stack Overflow the same as actual per-site-metas. Possibly because its url starts with meta, or summat. In any case, per-site-metas are not displayed in your associated accounts.

Comment: @Grace - I can see why this would happen for other new meta sites but isn't meta.stackoverflow.com a bit different from the new sites.  For a start the reputation is completely separate?

Comment: The other new meta sites were always absent from the profile. Which is why my guess is that new code has caused Meta Stack Overflow to be treated the same. It could be optimization update or summat which resulted in a looser check that simply didn't account for MSO's difference.

Comment: Didn't this happen when they changed data centers? I thought it was to be expected for awhile, but seems like it should be back to normal by now.

Comment: @Jon At that time, it was that you couldn't see any accounts when viewing on Meta Stack Overflow. Here, it's quite the opposite, and is more recently introduced.

Comment: I can't see my related accounts list on any site - the page just hangs and I can't access any SO site for the next 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @ChrisF - Works for me! :)

Comment: @Barry - I don't doubt that. I did post a question, but it's been deleted (it was a duplicate) and I can't find the "original" question any more. Nothing's changed in a couple of months though.

Comment: Ha - just gone a tried the accounts tab again and it works fine for me too. That'll teach me.

Answer (score 2):

The API isn't returning MSO as an associated account when asking for a user's associated accounts.  I'm assuming that the api is pulled to generate the list of associated accounts displayed in a user's profile.  (Or if not, common code used by both is the problem.)

I actually just posted [this issue](https://stackapps.com/q/1785/2286) on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) as I was noticing an issue with [StackFlair](http://stackflair.com).

EDIT:  This appears to have been resolved.